# How do I output two fields in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has two fields: current, and previous.

Here is the code:

```
                            <?
$username="*****";
$password="*****";
$database="******";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password) or die("Unable to connect to server");
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query='SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE current=1 OR previous=1';
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result); 

mysql_close();

?>
```

It then output it and manipulate it like this:

```
<div class="tasklist">
    <div class="currentProject">
    Current Project:
    </div>
<?
$i=0;

while ($i < $num) {
$title=mysql_result($result,$i,"Title");
$link=mysql_result($result,$i,"Weblink");
$description=mysql_result($result,$i,"Description");
$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
$howto=mysql_result($result,$i,"howto");
$blogpost=mysql_result($result,$i,"blogpost");
$done=mysql_result($result,$i,"done");
$current=mysql_result($result,$i,"current");
$previous=mysql_result($result,$i,"previous");

if ( $current == 1 ) {
    $current = "current";
} else {
    $current = "";
}

if ( $previous == 1 ) {
    $previous = "previous";
} else {
    $previous = "";
}

?>

    <div class="<? echo $done ?> task <? echo $id ?>" id="<? echo $current.$previous ?>">
            <div class="titleWrapper">
                <div class="title">
                    <a class="article"  href="<? echo $link ?>"><? echo $title ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div><BR>

<?
$i++;
}

echo "</div>";


?>
```

The problem is that since previous comes before current in the database, it outputs previous and then current.

**Question:**

How do I make sure to output `current` first, and then `previous`?

Comment: That's incredible ancient way to query a database. Where did you get that rarity? And your database structure is under questioning too

Comment: To be honest, I ripped it off of another coders work. I am not the best with PHP, and I asked a buddy to code that for me.... and mind being more helpful other than "database structure is under questioning too"?

Comment: If you can provide a better way to do it, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append this to your query `order by previous`.

It must work as long as current task registry has `previous=0` and previous task registry has `previous=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outputting both directly, store them until you actually have both, and then output both in the correct order.